# How to synchronize a MySQL database with a model?

Tags: mysql, asp.net, scaffolding

I added a new field to my 'Client' table. How can I save it in my database? I used the following command to generate my models: '

`dotnet-ef dbcontext scaffold "server=localhost;port=3307;database=XFOOD;user=root;password=root" Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql -o Models --force \```'

I've already used the command

```
'dotnet ef migrations add  initialEmail' ,
```

but it displays:

> '**table client already exists**'